# Statistics: Probability of (X > bigger number) given that (X > smaller number) = 0.7

Tags: statistics

The lifetime of a transistor is exponentially distributed. The probability that the lifetime is greater than 5 years is 0.7.

What is the probability that the lifetime is greater than 15 years?

I've stared at this problem for a while, only understanding that

if $X$ = lifetime in years, then $P(X > 5) = 0.7$

I'm not sure what to use in order to find $P(X > 15)$. I was thinking about using the exponential distribution formula, but that doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the exponential distribution, $P(X\gt 5)=e^{-5k}=.7$.
However $P(X\gt 15)=e^{-15k}=(e^{-5k})^3=.7^3=.343$

Answer (score 1):

$$P(t>5)=\int _5^\infty (1/\mu )e^{-t/\mu} = e^{-5/\mu}= 0.7 $$

$$P(t>15)=\int _{15}^\infty (1/\mu )e^{-t/\mu} = e^{-15/\mu}= (0.7)^3= 0.343$$